# Excel combobox Drop down loop

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I have a useform that has 30 comboboxes in their names (combobox1 to combobox30) and I want to add a list of combobox for everyone through For or For each  comboxlist (Gram , Ml , pice) I don't want to write it 30 times ..

```
Dim cmb As Object
Dim usf As UserForm

Set cmb = Me.cmb1
Set usf = Me

For cmb = 1 To 30
    With cmb
        .AddItem "Gram"
        .AddItem "Mil."
        .AddItem "Pice"
    End With
Next cmb
```

Comment: If these answers resolved your problem, you should accept an answer so that this questions becomes resolved.  If they didn't, maybe you can say why not :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the form's `Controls()` method:

```vb
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 30
    With Me.Controls("Combobox" & cmb)
        .AddItem "Gram"
        .AddItem "Mil."
        .AddItem "Pice"
    End With
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the controls, and if it's a combobox, then add the items.  The advantage here is you don't have to know ahead of time how many comboboxes there are.  I have this in the UserForm_Initialize() code.

```
Dim cmb As Control

For Each cmb In Me.Controls

    If TypeName(cmb) = "ComboBox" Then

        With cmb
            .AddItem "Gram"
            .AddItem "Mil."
            .AddItem "Pice"
        End With

    End If

 Next
```